# run quickfix engine

Tags: c++, quickfix

I'm trying to get started with c++ quickfix engine. I downloaded the project (VS2010 version).
The documentation is rather poor, so my understanding is that the project quickfix_vs10 is the actual library and the other projects that I would need to run are example_ordermatch_vs10, the executor_cpp_vs10 and the example_tradeclient_vs10.

so, my assumption is that it would go from client -> ordermatch ->executor.
The main problem I'm having right now is that each of those projects is looking for a "file".
The usage says: 
  **

> std::cout << "usage: " << argv[ 0 ]
>       << " FILE." << std::endl;
>       return 0;

**

Where do I get this file from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the quickfix config file. Here is a sample file for an initiator. Go through this [configuration for quickfix](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html). You have to set the same for the executor with connectiontype as an acceptor. You can modify the default values I have given to your liking.

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=ABCD1
HeartBtInt=20
SocketConnectHost=localhost
SocketConnectPort=8888
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ReconnectInterval=50
FileLogPath=C:\Log

# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
TransportDataDictionary=C:\FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=C:\FIX50SP2.xml
StartTime=07:15:00
EndTime=18:00:00
TargetCompID=PLUS
FileStorePath=C:\Log
```